# How to use the @Autowired filed when construct in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean use the "MongoTemplate" in construction,like this:

```
public class BasicRepository<T> implements DAO<T>{
...
  @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
  public BasicRepository(Class<?> typeParameterClass,DBConvertor<T> convertor){
        getLogger().info("create a Object of BasicRepository,type of "+typeParameterClass);
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
        mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(typeParameterClass);
        this.convertor = convertor;
    }
...
  }
```

configuration：

```
public class BeansConfiguration {
    @Bean
    DBConvertor<Topic> topicConvertor(){
        return new DBConvertor<>(Topic.class);
    }
    @Bean
    BasicRepository<Topic> topicDao(){
        return new BasicRepository<Topic>(Topic.class,topicConvertor());

    }
}
```

As you see,when construct the BasicRepository，it will throw the exception,because  “mongoTemplate” is null during constructing time.How can I do for this.

Comment: Check out `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Better, inject the template into the constructor instead of onto a field.

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired can not guarantee the constructor order. If you want to initialize the mongoTemplate first, you could use the mongoTemplate as a param of your constructor of BasicRepository.Then the Spring will do the dependent order for you.

Comment: Not in this case. They are invoking the constructor explicitly. They would need to propagate the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Seems missing configuration of MongoTemplate. And you also need to check where you calling this repository. Spring beans are initialized after configuration load, if you use beans before spring loaded, it will be null.